# validating only few fields for any specific submit button

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery Validation plugin ( http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ )

I have a very odd scenario in front of me.

I have one form, with 5 different submit buttons

```
<form id="frm1" name="frm1" method="post" action="save.php">
  ------- input fields here---
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="update account info">

  ------- input fields here---
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="update address info">

  ------- input fields here---
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="update credit-card info">

  ------- input fields here---
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="update bank info">

  ------- input fields here---
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="update other info">
</form>
```

Now, for each submit button, I need to validate a few fields (and not all fields)

Say for "update account info" submit, I need to validate following input fields with following ids:

```
 cust_fname
 cust_lname
 cust_age
```

Say for "update other info" submit, I need to validate following input fields with following ids:

```
 married
 childerns
```

How can I achieve following?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create 5 separate forms is the most easy way to do this. Then you can bind a different specific validation to each form.

Or you can bind a validation to each click on a submit button.
assuming you update your submitbutton to:

```
  <input type="submit" id="button_1" name="submit" value="update account info">
```

Then with jquery you can bind this with:

```
$("#button_1").live("click", function() {
    $("#frm1").validate({
        rules: {
            cust_fname: "required", // of course set different options for every field
            cust_lname: "required", 
            cust_age: "required"
        }
    }); 
});
```

And do this for every button.

**edit:** Live has been deprecated.

```
$("#button_1").on("click", function() {
    $("#frm1").validate({
        rules: {
            cust_fname: "required", // of course set different options for every field
            cust_lname: "required", 
            cust_age: "required"
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: [`live()` has been deprecated since jquery 1.7 and removed in 1.9](http://api.jquery.com/live/). Just use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) in stead.